# clearcase appends weird stuff

Tags: clearcase, garbage

I am getting some weird characters at the end of some of my files. 
The files are not checked out when this occurs and if I check them out and undo the check-outs these characters disappear.

The problem is it does this with files at random, not the same ones all the time, but a number of files here and there. One of the consequenses of these occurances is that eclipse projects cannot be loaded since the .project-file is seen as corrupt. Any suggestions as to why this happens?

I am sorry I cannot post any images. However, in text shown in notepad++ it is written as:

```
.... 
....
<last_line>[nul][nul][nul][nul][nul][nul][nul]...
```

by the way, [nul] has the value 0x00.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an encoding issue, like one described in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK39192), where Diffmerge incorrectly selects encoding based on locale.

You can check their encoding by editing them in Notepad++.
Check also your [ClearCase Unicode Type Manager](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/clearcase-unicode-typemanager/).

Depending on your ClearCase version, you [also had issue with the magic file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21321291).

Finally, check if you have some corrupt container associated with those files:
See [technote swg21222072 Type manager text_file_delta failed create_version operation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21222072).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. looks promising.